# How to perform double tap using Appium

Tags: c#, appium

I'm trying to simulate double tap using Appium + C#

```
TouchActions actions = new TouchActions(driver);
    public void PerformDoubleTap()
     {
         actions.DoubleTap(Element).Build().Perform();
     }
```

Using this code I'm getting next exception

```
System.ArgumentException : The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen.
```

Is there any way to perform double tap?

**Edited:**
Here is the class where I initialize driver

```
    public class BaseTest
    {
        protected static AndroidDriver<IWebElement> driver;
        AppiumLocalService service;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void BeforeClass()
        {
            service = AppiumLocalService.BuildDefaultService();
            service.Start();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeTest()
        {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(Settings.uri, Settings.GetAndroidDesiredCapabilities());
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void AfterTest()
        {
            driver.CloseApp();
        }
        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void AfterClass()
        {
            service.Dispose();
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What platform are you trying to test using appium? Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox, Android?

Comment: @IliassNassibane Android

Comment: How did you initialize the driver? Could you maybe add that piece of code to the question?